# Which rolls does the GM make in secret for the party?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

What are all the common skill checks or saving throw rolls that the GM makes in secret for the party? I would like list of all the secret rolls that the GM makes, that the party does not even know they are taking.

I know that passive spot checks can be rolled by either the GM or the players, but if the GM calls out, "make a spot check," the party will know something's up even if they roll low.

As an example:

> Jordan Bane the Fighter steps into a room. To his left is a crossbow trap mounted on the wall, ready to fire if he trips the trip wire at his feet. The GM asks Jordan Bane's player to make a spot check; he rolls a 2 and gets a total of 3 after bonuses for his check. The player rolls his eyes and tells rest of party, "Hey guys, I am not going any further. Maybe the rogue should check this way, now."

Total meta-game but could have been avoided if the GM simply rolled the spot check behind the GM screen and said "P-twang! a steel bolt flies through the air and strikes Jordan Bane in the left shoulder as he enters the goblin kitchen!"

So what are all the checks the GM may make in secret?

I am aware that a similar question was asked in a previous post but it dose not provide a list of the all the checks that would or should be rolled by the GM to prevent Meta.

Comment: Seems to be based on a mistaken belief that a canonical list exists of rolls that the GM may make in secret. It's different, but "there is no list, see this question" seems like an unnecessary answer.

Comment: See also: [How to roll perception checks for characters who aren't actively looking?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/16461/4398)

Comment: Also related: [What is the best way to do search, or spot test when players knowing the result of their roll will colour their perception of the result?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4155/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-search-or-spot-test-when-players-knowing-the-result)

Comment: Regarding your edit: what if that list doesn't exist or is impossible to exist? Does an answer that says, "That doesn't exist, see this other question" actually help more than "this is a duplicate of this, this, and that question"?

Comment: There is and can be no list of *every* possible roll a GM might want to keep secret. I guess it might be possible to codify a list of criteria that *some* GMs use to determine which rolls should be kept secret, but to a great extent which rolls should and shouldn't be public depends on the playstyle and desires of the GM and table.

Comment: @GMJoe Thank you for that answer, it would appear as though I will have to compile my own list of what I find acceptable to take out of the players hand even though I am a strong advocate of letting the players roll anything attached to their fate, I have found that many situations are better kept secret from the players to keep the game more accurate in what the player and the character know or are suppose to know.